# assign a variable to all the files in a directory that have been modified in the last week through ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

I need to assign a variable to all of the files in a directory that have been modified in the last week. i know how to sort the items but I don't know how to only get the files within the past week.

```
files_sorted_by_time = Dir['*'].sort_by{ |f| File.mtime(f)  }.reverse
```

I know it has to do with Time.now or something of the sort. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).  Also, 604800 is the number of minutes in a week.  I'm not sure if that is legitimate to use or not.

```
files_sorted_by_time = Dir['*'].select { 
  |f| ((Time.now - File.mtime(f)).to_i / 604800) < 7 }
```

Comment: one more question, if i wanted to convert that, to instead of local, to use Net::ftp, how would i do that?

Comment: @Chase I'm not sure I follow. Would you just get the list first using Net::FTP, then filter?

Comment: I need to run this code on a server. I'm new to Ruby's file stuff. could I just replace Dir with ftp? heres the code to explain it. http://pastebin.com/WrrduZsm

Comment: @Chase Off the top of my head I would just either fetch the files in questions and then filter or filter and then push if that makes sense.

Comment: The reason I need to get it on the server is because I need to find the files i need to download from the server. The script downloads the selected files, converts them to mp4, and then reuploads them. this is why i need to sort everything out on the server. If I download them all, that would take up a good 40 gb. Thankyou for your time, I'm sorry if this is too much of a pain.

Comment: To run the code on a server via FTP, you have to do it all with the file list returned by FTP. [Ruby's Net::FTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html) has the `list` method to return matching filenames. Any further discussion should occur in a separate question after you've tried writing code to solve the problem.

Comment: @the Tin Man so like this: files = ftp.list.select { |f| ((Time.now - File.mtime(f)).to_i / 10080) < 7 }

Comment: No. That won't work via FTP. `File.mtime` only works with local files.

Comment: so how would I write that for ftp?

Comment: @theTinMan Did I calculate the time difference incorrectly?  I see you did 7 * 24 * 60 * 60.

Comment: You need to figure out what that represents. Hint, look at how Time's math works.

Comment: @theTinMan I got confused, I guess it is in seconds eh? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-2D

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's [`Find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class makes it easy to do recursive-descent searches from a starting path:

```
require 'find'

LAST_WEEK = Time.now - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)

abort "Missing path to search" if ARGV.empty?

puts "Scanning for files modified since #{ LAST_WEEK }"

week_old_files = []
Find.find(ARGV.shift) do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.
      Find.prune       # Don't look any further into hidden directories.
    else
      next
    end
  else
    mod_time = File.mtime(path)
    week_old_files << [mod_time, path] if mod_time >= LAST_WEEK
  end
end

puts week_old_files.map{ |a| '%s : %s' % a }
```

Running that returns stuff like:

```
Scanning for files modified since 2013-07-25 19:23:36 -0700
2013-08-01 09:05:22 -0700 : /Users/Cthulhu/Desktop/.DS_Store
2013-08-01 19:23:26 -0700 : /Users/Cthulhu/Desktop/test.rb
```

NOTE: This descends into child directories, and is the basis for many disk based utilities. To avoid descending you can prune every directory found:

```
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    Find.prune
  else
    mod_time = File.mtime(path)
    week_old_files << [mod_time, path] if mod_time >= LAST_WEEK
  end
```